# ElasticSearch: Retrieve field and it's normalization

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to retrieve a field as well as it's normalized version from Elasticsearch.

Here's my index definition and data

```
PUT normalizersample
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "refresh_interval": "60s",
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "german_normalization",
            "asciifolding"
          ],
          "type": "custom"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "myField": {
        "type": "text",
        "store": true,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "store": true
          },
          "normalized": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "store": true,
            "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST normalizersample/_doc/1
{
  "myField": ["Andreas", "Ämdreas", "Anders"]
}
```

My first approach was to use scripted fields like

```
GET /myIndex/_search
{
  "size": 100, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "script": "doc['myField.keyword']"
    },
    "normalized": {
      "script": "doc['myField.normalized']"
    }
  }
}
```

However, since *myField* is an array, this returns two lists of strings per ES document and each of them are sorted alphabetically. Hence, the corresponding entries might not match to each other due to the normalization.

```
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "normalizersample",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "fields" : {
          "de" : [
            "amdreas",
            "anders",
            "andreas"
          ],
          "keyword" : [
            "Anders",
            "Andreas",
            "Ämdreas"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

While I would like to retrieve [(Andreas, andreas), (Ämdreas, amdreas) (Anders, anders)] or a similar format where I can match every entry to its normalization.
The only way I found was to call Term Vectors on both fields since they contain a position field, but this seems like a huge overhead to me. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html)

Is there a simpler way to retrieve tuples with the keyword and the normalized field?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you want to get the normalized version and keyword version of your fields in index? can you give some samples and expected o/p ?

Comment: @PrernaGupta Yes, I want to retrieve both. I've added samples, hope it's clear now.